# Wowza Live Stream - How get Name of Current Video

Tags: video, stream, live, wowza

I need know, how i can get name of current video in a Live Stream?
This is possible? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [quick start guide](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?3-quick-start-guide).

For live streams, you'll usually create a .stream file with the format *[protocol]://0.0.0:*, and your live stream will need to point to the wowza server using that protocol and port.  You'll then connect to the live stream with a url like *rtmp://[wowzaserver]/live/xxyy.stream*, where xxyy is the name of your aforementioned .stream file.